# qml textInput.Password Shift behavior

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a question about different shift behavior with QtVirtualKeyboard on text and password fields.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard 2.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Window {
    id: window
    width: 800
    height: 480
    color: "#F6F6F6"

    MouseArea  {
        id: content
        width: window.width

        Column {
            id: textEditors
            spacing: 15
            x: 12
            y: 12
            width: parent.width - 26

            Label {
                color: "#565758"
                text: "Tap fields to enter text"
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            }
            TextField {
                width: parent.width
                placeholderText: "One line field"
                inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhPreferLowercase
            }
            TextField {
                id: passwordField
                width: parent.width
                echoMode: TextField.Password
                placeholderText: "Password field"
                // changes do not work
                inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhNoAutoUppercase | Qt.ImhPreferLowercase | Qt.ImhSensitiveData | Qt.ImhNoPredictiveText
            }
        }
    }

    InputPanel {
        id: inputPanel
        z: 2
        y: window.height
        width: window.width

        states: State {
            name: "visible"
            when: inputPanel.active
            PropertyChanges {
                target: inputPanel
                y: window.height - inputPanel.height
            }
        }
        transitions: Transition {
            from: ""
            to: "visible"
            reversible: true
            ParallelAnimation {
                NumberAnimation {
                    properties: "y"
                    duration: 250
                    easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I click on shift `basic` TextField, only first letter is a capital one. This is the right behavior. But on the `echoMode: textInput.Password` shift has a caps-lock functionality, which I don't want.
Is it possible to override it somehow, or is it a QT feature, which is not possible to change?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard 2.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Window {
    id: window
    width: 800
    height: 480
    color: "#F6F6F6"
    visible: true

    MouseArea  {
        id: content
        width: window.width

        Column {
            id: textEditors
            spacing: 15
            x: 12
            y: 12
            width: parent.width - 26

            Label {
                color: "#565758"
                text: "Tap fields to enter text"
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            }
            TextField {
                width: parent.width
                placeholderText: "One line field"
                inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhPreferLowercase
            }
            TextField {
                id: passwordField
                width: parent.width
                echoMode: TextField.Password
                placeholderText: "Password field"
                // changes do not work
                inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhNoAutoUppercase | Qt.ImhPreferLowercase | Qt.ImhSensitiveData | Qt.ImhNoPredictiveText

                onTextChanged: console.log(text)
            }
        }
    }

    InputPanel {
        id: inputPanel
        z: 2
        y: window.height
        width: window.width

        property bool shiftActive: (InputContext == null) ? null : InputContext.shiftActive
        property variant shiftKey: null

        function findKey(parent) {
            if (parent === null) {
                return null
            }

            var children = parent.children
            if (children === undefined || children === null) {
                return null
            }

            var obj = null

            for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                obj = children[i]

                if (obj instanceof ShiftKey) {
                    return obj
                }

                obj = findKey(obj)

                if (obj === null) {
                    continue
                }

                if (obj instanceof ShiftKey) {
                    return obj
                }
            }

            return null
        }

        Timer {
            id: timer
            interval: 0
            repeat: false
            running: false
            onTriggered: {
                inputPanel.shiftKey.clicked()
            }
        }

        Connections {
            target: (InputContext.inputItem != null && InputContext.inputItem.echoMode === TextField.Password) ? InputContext.inputItem : null
            onTextChanged: {
                if (inputPanel.shiftActive) {
                    if (inputPanel.shiftKey == null) {
                        inputPanel.shiftKey = inputPanel.findKey(inputPanel.keyboard)
                    }

                    timer.start()
                }
            }
        }


        states: State {
            name: "visible"
            when: inputPanel.active
            PropertyChanges {
                target: inputPanel
                y: window.height - inputPanel.height
            }
        }
        transitions: Transition {
            from: ""
            to: "visible"
            reversible: true
            ParallelAnimation {
                NumberAnimation {
                    properties: "y"
                    duration: 250
                    easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First, thank you for your answer ;). Is it really needed to use this "complicate" way?  

Anyway, looks like, that is not working.  
```qml
property bool shiftActive: (InputContext == null) ? null : InputContext.shiftActive
// main.qml:50:36: Unable to assign [undefined] to bool
```
For test I changed it to `true`, but there are some next errors:  
```qml
if (obj instanceof ShiftKey) {
// main.qml:68: TypeError: Type error
```

Comment: What is your Qt version ?

Comment: Ubuntu with QT version `5.9.5`

Comment: Too old, this code works with Qt 5.14 at least

Answer (score 0):

I've founded one drastic way. Now it won't go into caps-lock state, and works like shift. But there isn't an option to enable it somehow.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard 2.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Window {
    id: window
    width: 800
    height: 480
    color: "#F6F6F6"

    MouseArea  {
        id: content
        width: window.width

        Column {
            id: textEditors
            spacing: 15
            x: 12
            y: 12
            width: parent.width - 26

            Label {
                color: "#565758"
                text: "Tap fields to enter text"
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            }
            TextField {
                width: parent.width
                placeholderText: "One line field"
            }
            TextField {
                id: passwordField
                width: parent.width
                echoMode: TextField.PasswordEchoOnEdit
                placeholderText: "Password field"
                inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhAutoUppercase | Qt.ImhPreferLowercase | Qt.ImhSensitiveData | Qt.ImhNoPredictiveText

                onTextChanged: {
                    InputContext.capsLock = false
                }
            }
        }
    }

    InputPanel {
        id: inputPanel
        z: 2
        y: window.height
        width: window.width

        states: State {
            name: "visible"
            when: inputPanel.active
            PropertyChanges {
                target: inputPanel
                y: window.height - inputPanel.height
            }
        }
        transitions: Transition {
            from: ""
            to: "visible"
            reversible: true
            ParallelAnimation {
                NumberAnimation {
                    properties: "y"
                    duration: 250
                    easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The main problem that, that I wanted to the same behavior on the all inputs, not only in this example.